# Why is getAttribute() in js giving error :?

Tags: javascript

following is the code i wrote.
If i change code in for loop to i<len-1 then its working just fine except for last link
But if i keep it like i<len, it isn't working for any link.

```
const allLists = document.querySelectorAll("a:link");
var len = allLists.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  allLists[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const href = allLists[i].getAttribute("href");
    console.log(href);
    if (href == "#") {
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Error:
script.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAttribute')
at HTMLAnchorElement.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add details about the error?

Comment: Also, could you try using arrow functions for `click` handlers, something like this `(e) => {...}` instead of `function (e) {...}`

Comment: "*... giving error*" - what error?  [Please do not post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: As @Xupitan has conveyed, the i variable behaves different due to closure concept of for loop. Sometimes using 'this' is also helpful in context of eventlisteners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `i` variable by `len` after your looping

Then, each time the click event is called, the code to be run will always be:

```
const href = allLists[len].getAttribute("href");
```

This problem is a `closure` problem you can see more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

The revised code will look like : (change `var` to `let`)

```js
const allLists = document.querySelectorAll("a:link");
var len = allLists.length;

for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  allLists[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const href = allLists[i].getAttribute("href");
    console.log(href);
    if (href == "#") {
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<a href="1">1</a>
<a href="2">2</a>
<a href="3">3</a>
<a href="4">4</a>
```

Comment: I understand this would work in a global context, but would this also work if the code was wrapped in a function?

Comment: with let declaration, variable scope is only block, not global

Comment: That’s what I mean.

Comment: so wherever you put a block declared with let it will only work in that block, global or function

Comment: I know that’s what I’m saying…

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Mozilla developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) “ querySelectorAll() behaves differently than most common JavaScript DOM libraries, which might lead to unexpected results.”

So I would suggest following the docs and code a ‘forEach’ loop instead of a ‘for’ loop.